# How to make right overflow text in input in materializecss?

Tags: html, css, materialize

I got a list of companies names in  . Some of them can have name with length till 100 characters. And its looks not very nice when user pick it.
[image]

I tried these rules

```
{
  text-overflow:ellipsis; 
  overflow: hidden; 
  white-space: nowrap; 
  max-width: 250px;
}
```

but its not working.
What should I do?

Comment: I used your CSS and it worked perfectly fine for me. Without seeing more of your code I can't say for certain but I suggest trying to inspect the page and seeing if anything is overriding any of your styles.

Answer (score 0):

All you really need is:

```
input[type=text] {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

But,it seems that materialize only actions the css rule after a second click - the first click or tap being the choice, still displays the option as traditionally cut off.

https://codepen.io/doughballs/pen/LYVVXJM